# How to present editable input to a user with BASH and ZSH?

Tags: bash, input, zsh, readline

I need to accept user input within a shell script that can run both in BASH and ZSH. I'm accustomed to using `readline` in other languages, but this doesn't seem to be a viable option in shell scripting.

An example prompt might be:

```
Please enter the value> 1234_
```

How can I present a user with editable input that has a default value that can be edited (backspaced) that's compatible with both shells?

Comment: For zsh, you probably want to look at the [`vared` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/zsh_a4.pdf#165) of the ZLE module.  It a guess, `i=1234; vared -p 'Please enter the value> ' i`

Comment: There isn't anything that will work in both shells, because each shell uses a different line editor (Readline for `bash`, ZLE for `zsh`).

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks ! You made my day :-)   
   
You may also want to include a variable (e.g., called "answer") in which you store the user input:   
   
`read -e -p 'Please enter the value> ' -i '1234' answer`   
results in something like: `Please enter the value> 1236`.   
Show the edited user input like: `echo "$answer"`   
`1236`

Comment: @BernieReiter: This is of course possible but not absolutely necessary. If no variable is specified, `read` uses the variable `REPLY`. The code is of course easier to understand if you specify a variable.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks again! Learn everyday something new and worthwhile :-)

Comment: @cyrus I turned your comment into an answer below. IMO probably should have been an answer originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [@cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) mentioned in the comments, but is better directly as an answer instead:

```
read -e -p 'Please enter the value> ' -i '1234' myvar
echo $myvar
```

results in an editable default of `1234`

```
Please enter the value> 1234
1234
```

Comment: The output is then located in the variable `REPLY`.

Comment: This does not seem to work in zsh: `read: -p: no coprocess`

Answer (score -2):

If I did not misunderstand ...
In terms of "Backspace" functionality, to erase the last characters and add some new ..
This works in both shells with a simple "read" in the script.

```
echo -n "Enter value > "
read v
echo $v
```

If you have other issues, could you kindly rephrase to make your question clearer ?
What do you use (Example Code).
What do you perform exactly in terms of editing (only BS or do you mean line editing commands CTRL-A, etc)
What is the result / error, what you want to get fixed.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know zsh at all, but from a Bash perspective: `echo -n` is non-portable; `read` other than at the beginning of line will confuse readline's idea of column position.  That's why `read` has a `-p` option.

Comment: This doesn't provide the *initial value*, which is the main point of the question.